# Query Totals for rows and columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need help to combine the following commands to use a single Google Query command to obtain the **Totals** for **Rows** and **Columns** without relying on Pivot Tables:

QUERY 1 =QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C16, "SELECT A, SUM(C) GROUP BY A PIVOT B",1)

QUERY 2 =QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C16, "Select SUM (C) GROUP BY A label SUM (C) 'NAME ROW TOTALS'")

QUERY 3 ={transpose(Query(TESTDATA!A1:C16, "Select SUM (C) GROUP BY B label SUM (C) 'MONTH COLUMN TOTALS'"))}

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15i1E8AZHORRmPlu1VQqFRN1_7-aUyAz-hlYMOUtIlY4/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to return the following result:

[image]

Thank you very much
JA

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
={{QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C, "select A,sum(C) group by A pivot B", 1),
   QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C, "select sum(C) group by A label sum(C) 'NAME TOTAL'")}; TRANSPOSE(
   QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C, "select sum(C) group by B label sum(C) 'MONTH COLUMN TOTALS'"))}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the original Transpose Query that was returning to incorrect column totals.

Answer (score 0):

={{QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C,"select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B",1),
QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C,"select sum(C) where A is not null group by A label sum(C) 'NAME TOTAL'")};{TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:C,"select sum(C)  where A is not null  group by B label sum(C) 'MONTH COLUMN TOTALS'")),SUM($C$2:C)}}

Comment: This would be a lot easier to read if you formatted it as a [code block] and added some line breaks.